# XSD - element that contains one mandatory and one optional child element ( but both of them have to appear min once)

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a element *A* which contains two child elements *B* and *C*, child elements have to appear in the specific order ( *B* first, *C* second ) and *A* contains at least one pair of *B* and *C* (where *B* is mandatory and *C* is optional). For instance, a valid example would be:

```
<A>
  <B></B>
  <C></C>
  <B></B>
  <B></B>
  <C></C>
</A>
```

I tried this,

```
<xsd:complexType name="A">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="B" type="BType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="C" type="CType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="B" type="BType"/>
            <xsd:element name="C" type="CType" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

but in my solution

```
<A><C></C></A>
```

would be valid (but I need at least one pair of B and C)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsd:complexType name="A">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="B" type="BType"/>
        <xsd:element name="C" type="CType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Is in this case possible to have just A and B (without C)?

Comment: Yes, that's allowed by the schema that I posted.

Comment: Thank you for your help, probably my explemantion is not very clear, 
I need the schema where A contains at least one pair of B,C (and arbitrary number of just Bs)

Comment: I believe that is exactly what the above schema specifies. Currently your question only contains one valid example. Please can you add multiple valid and invalid examples to explain your requirements.

Comment: valid: 
| A,B,C  |
| A,B,C,B,C,B,C... |
|  A,B,C,B,B,B,B... |
| A,B,C,B,B,B,B,C,B,C.... |
| A,B,B,C   |
| A,B,B,B,B,C  |


invalid:
| A,C |
|A,C,C,C... |
|A,C,B |
| A,C,B,C,C,C... |
| A,C,B,C,B,C...  |

Comment: Please can you edit your question and put those valid/invalid examples into the question. I believe the schema that I posted will correctly match/reject all of those examples. Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsd:element name=“A”>
  <xsd:complexType name=“AType”>
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs=”unbounded” >
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name=“B” type=“BType”/>
        <xsd:element name=“C” type=“CType”/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name=“B” type=“BType”/>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Can this be possible solution?